# RoR Routing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Only recently have I started experiencing this problem. I have a completely custom RoR eCommerce site and we just finished redesigning the website. Somewhere in the process a routing issue has popped up and I can't seem to pinpoint why it's doing this now when before there was no issue.

The URI is viewed as:

```
/orders/295829fb4/items/379
```

Heroku logs are spitting out this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/orders/295829fb4/items/379"):
```

Here is my routes.rb for orders

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => (Rails.env.production? ? "https" : "http") } do

    resources :orders, :only => [:show, :cart] do

        member do

            get :cart

        end

        resources :items, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy], :controller => 'order_items'

        resource  :address, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

        resource  :payment, :only => [:new, :create]

        resource  :discount, :only => [:create, :destroy]

        resource  :shipping_method, :only => [:update]

    end

end

 cart_order GET    /orders/:id/cart(.:format)                                                     {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"orders", :action=>"cart"}
                        order_items POST   /orders/:order_id/items(.:format)                                              {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"order_items", :action=>"create"}
                         order_item GET    /orders/:order_id/items/:id(.:format)                                          {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"order_items", :action=>"show"}
                         order_item PUT    /orders/:order_id/items/:id(.:format)                                          {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"order_items", :action=>"update"}
                         order_item DELETE /orders/:order_id/items/:id(.:format)                                          {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"order_items", :action=>"destroy"}
                      order_address POST   /orders/:order_id/address(.:format)                                            {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"addresses", :action=>"create"}
                  new_order_address GET    /orders/:order_id/address/new(.:format)                                        {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"addresses", :action=>"new"}
                 edit_order_address GET    /orders/:order_id/address/edit(.:format)                                       {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"addresses", :action=>"edit"}
                      order_address PUT    /orders/:order_id/address(.:format)                                            {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"addresses", :action=>"update"}
                      order_payment POST   /orders/:order_id/payment(.:format)                                            {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"payments", :action=>"create"}
                  new_order_payment GET    /orders/:order_id/payment/new(.:format)                                        {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"payments", :action=>"new"}
                     order_discount POST   /orders/:order_id/discount(.:format)                                           {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"discounts", :action=>"create"}
                     order_discount DELETE /orders/:order_id/discount(.:format)                                           {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"discounts", :action=>"destroy"}
              order_shipping_method PUT    /orders/:order_id/shipping_method(.:format)                                    {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"shipping_methods", :action=>"update"}
                              order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                                                          {:protocol=>"https", :controller=>"orders", :action=>"show"}
```

Comment: Can you also post the output from `rake routes` ?

Comment: Added the rake routes pertaining to orders.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
  resources :items, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy], :controller => 'order_items'
```

Needs the :show method for that route to work.

```
  resources :items, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy], :controller => 'order_items'
```